# Deserializing JSON in .NET - Property with forward slashes

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json-deserialization

I have JSON like this that I'm trying to deserialize into a .NET Core 3.1 C# object.

```
{
  "meta": {
    "/workers/assignments/myItems": {
      "codeList": {
        "listItems": [
          {
            "codeValue": "KEY1",
            "shortName": "This is item 1"
          },
          {
            "codeValue": "KEY2",
            "shortName": "This is item 2"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My classes look like this:

```
 class Meta {
        [JsonProperty("/workers/assignments/myItems")]
        public ItemsMeta Items {get;set;}
    }

    class ItemsMeta {
        public CodeList codeList { get; set; }
    }

    class CodeList {
        public List<ListItem> listItems { get; set; }
    }

    public class ListItem {
        public string codeValue { get; set; }
        public string shortName { get; set; }
        public string longName { get; set; }
    }
```

But `var meta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Entities.Generated.Meta>(json);` has a null reference for the Items property.

What am I doing wrong? Is this possible without a custom JSON parser? I've tried both Newtonsoft and System.Text.Json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `meta` tag is within another object or `RootObject`. Add that to your model and deserialize your json to that object:

```
public class Meta
{
    [JsonProperty("/workers/assignments/myItems")]
    public ItemsMeta Items { get; set; }
}

public class ItemsMeta
{
    public CodeList codeList { get; set; }
}

public class CodeList
{
    public List<ListItem> listItems { get; set; }
}

public class ListItem
{
    public string codeValue { get; set; }
    public string shortName { get; set; }
    public string longName { get; set; }
}

public class Rootobject
{
    public Meta Meta { get; set; }
}
```

And now deserialize:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```